# looking for a way to add reserved words in data definitions in haskell

Tags: haskell

As the title says im trying to build an interpreter for Imperative languages in Haskell. Iv done 90% of it, nevertheless, im trying to build If statements, and my question is, how will i define a new datatype lets say :

data x = if boolExp then exp else exp.

I understand that i could re-write this with something like doIf boolExp exp exp. But i would like to see if i could use those reserved keywords just for fun (and maybe conciseness).
Note that both boolExp and exp are defined in my language and work correctly( i even evaluate them to get the actual expression "value").

So bottom line is, how will i add reserved keywords in my data definition as required above?

Comment: Wouldn't a constructor have to be called `If` anyway and be prefix instead of "misfix"? Also, how do you intend to resolve the inherent ambiguity this would bring?

Comment: my question having a negative answer doesn't make it a stupid question in my opinion, iv searched everywhere and couldnt find an answer.Hence  my question, why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is the `RebindableSyntax` extension in GHC, which treats `if cond then truePart else falsePart` as if you had written `ifThenElse cond truePart falsePart`, with whatever `ifThenElse` is in scope.

You can't use this for a data constructor, but you can write something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

import Prelude

data BoolExp = Foo
  deriving Show

data Exp = If BoolExp Exp Exp | Bar
  deriving Show

ifThenElse :: BoolExp -> Exp -> Exp -> Exp
ifThenElse = If

example = if Foo then Bar else Bar

main = print example
```

Running this prints `If Foo Bar Bar`.

However, unless you're writing some kind of internal DSL where this would make sense, I strongly recommend just sticking with the regular syntax like `If cond truePart falsePart`. Writing it this way has no real benefit and serves only to confuse people when reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one dumb way to get the *kind* of syntax you want:

```
data If a = If Bool () a () a
if_ = If
then_ = ()
else_ = ()

expr :: If Int
expr = if_ (3 > 4) then_ 0 else_ 1
```

But like hammar said, if you want to actually make use of the keywords `if`, `then`, and `else`, you'll need to use RebindableSyntax, or some other preprocessor/macro, otherwise you'll be in conflict with Haskell syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the suggestions already given, you can also use the quasiquote feature of Template Haskell to create whatever syntax you want.